# How can I check the type of a React functional component at run-time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundling-and-minification

Say I have apples and bananas:

```
function Apple() { 
  return <div>Apple</div>
}

function Banana() {
  return <div>Banana</div>
}
```

I want to put some in a `<FruitSalad>`:

```
<FruitSalad>
  <Apple>
  <Apple>
  <Banana>
</FruitSalad>
```

How can I check their type at run time?

```
function FruitSalad({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {

  React.Children.map(children, child => {
    if (isBanana(child)) { console.log('I am a banana!') }
  })

  return <div>{children}</div>
}

function isBanana(element: any): element is JSX.Element {
  return React.isValidElement(element) && ???
}
```

What is the definition of `isBanana()` here? Relying on the name of anything ("Banana") is problematic because it may break when code is minified in production. So what's a safe way to see if a child is a `Banana` component?

Answer (score 0):

You could identify them by setting their [`displayName`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#displayname) property:

```js
function Apple() { 
  return <div>Apple</div>
}
Apple.displayName = "apple"

function Banana() {
  return <div>Banana</div>
}
Banana.displayName = "banana"
```

Then when looping through children, check this property:

```js
React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
  if (child.type.displayName == "banana") { console.log('I am a banana!) }
})
```

Demo:

[image: Edit interesting-rosalind-9dp8y4]